# render a show view from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I always get the error

> No route matches {:action=>"index", :blog_id=>nil, :controller=>"comments"} missing required keys: [:blog_id]

when I'm rendering the **show** action from a different controller:

```
  def create
    @blog = Blog.find params[:blog_id]
    @comment = @blog.comments.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render template: 'blogs/show' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error happens after validating. The specific line of code responsible for this is `format.html { render template: 'blogs/show' }`

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Here's my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do   resources :comments

  devise_for :users

  resources :blogs do
    resources :comments
    member do
      get '/update/(:status)', to: 'blogs#update_blog_status'
      put :rename
    end
    collection do
      put :destroy_multiple
    end

   root 'blogs#index'
end
```

As you can see from the error, why is rails matching me with `:action => 'index', controller: 'comments'` when I clearly want to render `blogs/show`?

**Edit 2**

If you're wondering what I'm doing, I wanted to comment on a blog. So the comment form is in `blogs/1` and I wanted to test if validation works. When I didn't enter anything in my comment text area, I'm getting the error.

**Edit 3** Posting my blogs/show.html.haml

Forgive me but my show.html is in `haml` format. If you're not familiar with haml, convert it to erb here http://www.haml-converter.com/

**blogs/show.html.haml**

```
%p#notice= notice

%h1
  %strong= @blog.title

%hr

%p
  = @blog.content

%hr

%p
  %strong Comments:

= form_for @comment, url: blog_comments_path(blog_id: params[:id]) do |f|
  = f.text_area :message
  %br
  = f.submit "Post Comment"

%br
%p
  %strong All Comments:

- @all_comments.each do |comment|
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-body
      = comment.message


= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(@blog)
|
= link_to 'Back', blogs_path
```

Comment: what you have written in the route.rb file .

Comment: The problem comes from `blogs/show`, there is a route helper and a variable with was not assigned

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire I assure you, I have assigned all variables for the show action in blogs_controller.

Comment: Please, paste your blog/show.html.erb file

Comment: @Rodrigo, I just posted my show.html.haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the view:

```
blog_comments_path(@blog)
```

The POST with the comment is made to the URL: `/blogs/:blog_id/comments`.
When the validation fails, you trying to build the form's URL using `params[:id]` which is `nil`. Using `@blog` instance should solve the problem.

Comment: sorry, same error. I even tried `render 'blogs/show', params: { blog_id: @blog.id }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem come as blog resources create 'index' method routes '/blogs', so when you are trying to access 'blogs/show', its try to find 'index' method for that controllers.